# How do I install electrical through "new work" stucco?

Tags: electrical, moisture, stucco

See also [How do I install electrical through existing stucco (e.g. "old work")](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/14600/how-do-i-install-electrical-through-stucco) which deals with the old work situation.

What are the best practice products and procedures for installing an exterior light, on a wall that will be re-stuccoed?

While I am looking for a general answer, I do have a specific wall in mind.  This plastic box is installed on top of a circle of plywood with one screw.  The paper is cut around the box and caulked to the outer layer.  The box is not waterproof itself.  I have been unable to find a stucco depth waterproof box:

[image]

Comment: Your picture does not clearly show how it has been affixed.  Please improve your description of how the box has been mounted.

Comment: Just use any water proof /outdoor light fixture and seal it the same way as you have done with that blue box thing. Why do3s it have to be special? As long as the pipe with the cables is sealed and the wire enters from the top and makes a `U` inside a water proof light fitting- you good to go.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like your problem is stucco depth (1 in or more) versus drywall depth (1/2 in or 5/8 in).

Can you find a mud ring/box extender that's appropriately gasketed for use in a wet environment? If so, you can use that to bulk up the box depth.

You could also look for a deeper box. That one looks like a pancake.

Or, since you mounted the box on plywood anyway, just use several pieces of plywood to push the base of the box out to an appropriate depth.

Comment: If you can't find appropriate extension rings, get an 1-1/2" plastic box and cut/grind it to the right depth. The screw holes usually run deep enough so that the fixture screws will still work. Feed carefully, the plastic shatters easily.

Comment: And actually, IIRC, if the box is in-wall rather than surface mount, you don't even have to bother with damp/wet-rated kit. Don't quote me on that; look it up.